# Dynamic angular form group array with conditional show/hide

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

In my angular application I have to implement quite complicated form.
User may dynamically add/remove/modify form's elements (groups).

Each element is a group of inputs where some of them are conditionally being hidden/visible (based on a selection of one of them dropdowns in the group). These conditional groups may contain different quantity of fields, some of them may be required, some not.

New array element cannot be added until all visible fields are validated.
Whole form should be easy to serialize (as its stored on backend) and deserialized.

I am pretty sure that I have to use form array's. I have been checking some 3rd party libraries like [ng dynamic forms](https://github.com/udos86/ng-dynamic-forms) but still I am not sure how to implement what I need. Any ideas how can I achieve this?

[image]

Form is used to add/edit/remove following objects:

```
tasks": [
        {
            "uuid": "4e7e6737-8557-4a05-bb78-808f8a10daa4",
            "created": "2018-12-17T15:19:07.328408+01:00",
            "title": "TITLE (first input)", // value of first input
            "modified": "2018-12-17T15:19:07.328440+01:00",
            "task_type": "SEND_EMAIL",// this is value of TYPE DROPDOWN

            "time_value": 2, // value of 2nd input in array element
            "time_unit": "DAYS", // value of 3rd input in array element
            "time_dir": "BEFORE",// value of 4th input in array element
            "process": "5f185517-40df-43e8-b677-3cf929b21638",
            "config": {
                // here all fields are selected form group inputs
                "uuid": "b21f4cdf-22ba-42cd-81fa-7e7f1f84e6d1",
                "created": "2018-12-17T15:20:25.350927+01:00",
                "modified": "2018-12-17T15:20:25.350948+01:00",
                "email_title": "Email title",
                "email_from_address": "example@example.com",
                "email_from_name": "Hello",
                "email_content": "Email body",
            }
        }
    ],
```

TYPE DROPDOWN options are for exmaple:
"SEND EMAIL" - if selected visible group will show fields like "Email title", "Email from", "Email content" etc
"CREATE EVENT"- if selected visible group will show fields like "Event date and time", "Event duration" etc

When deserializing form, each task's "config" object will contain particular fields for a selected type.

Comment: can you provide the JSON object of this form?

Comment: Can you narrow your requirenments by providing some piece of code demonstrating the issue?

Comment: can you provide code that you've tried ?

Comment: @AjayOjha I've added a json

Comment: in your dynamic form is there any conditional validation or validation rules are coming from the server? I will include that also in my providing example

Comment: @AjayOjha I don't think so. Only one catch is that "config" object may contain different fields (depends on what was selected in TYPE DROPDOWN). And some of them may be required or not, of may require specific input format.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, when user selects 'SEND_EMAIL' task type then all config properties will be displayed, right? 
if the user selects another task type then respective task type properties will be displayed.

Comment: @AjayOjha I have added some description. config properties are generated dynamically, depending on what action was created

Comment: @dease did you find a solution eventually? I have the exact same problem :)

Answer (score 0):

the easer way is has an array of formGroup, the formGroup must be have all the fields (independent of the value of "dropdown").

It's could think that when we make a form of the type of

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
```

"form" must be a FormGroup, but it can be a FormArray itself

So, an full example can be like, see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1k9zcu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <div *ngFor="let controls of form.controls;let i=index;let last=last" 
            [formGroupName]="i">
        <input formControlName="field1">
        <input formControlName="field2">
        <button type="button" *ngIf="last" 
            [disabled]="!form.controls[i].valid" (click)="addLine()">
            Add
        </button>
    </div>
  </form>
  {{form?.value|json}}
```

Allways we have an FormArray it's util to have a function that received data or null and return a FormGroup. Allways we have a Form it's util to have a function that received data and return the form

```
  export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
      form:FormArray;  //see that our Form is directly a FormArray

      constructor(private fb:FormBuilder){}
      ngOnInit()
      {
        this.form=this.createForm(null); //At first we create an empty form
      }

      createForm(data:any[]):FormArray
      {
         //controls is an array of FormGroup
         let controls:FormGroup[]=
            data?data.map(x=>this.createLineArray(x))
                :[this.createLineArray(null)];
         return this.fb.array(controls);
      }

      createLineArray(data:any):FormGroup
      {
          return this.fb.group({
            field1:[data && data.field2?data.field2:null,Validators.required],
            field2:[data && data.field1?data.field1:null,Validators.required]
          })
      }

      //addLine simply push a new line in the array
      addLine()
      {
        this.form.push(this.createLineArray(null));
      }
```